# Phonegap Cordova - cordova-plugin-googlemaps Plugin Search bar does nothing

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, maps

I'm following this tutorial: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Map

I have added the searchBox HTML but the search box doesn't do anything. I'm able to type in it though. Am I missing something? I've read the entire thing from the start multiple times.

Map loads fine and I'm able to navigate by scrolling.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
      var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

  // Initialize the map view
  map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);

  // Wait until the map is ready status.
  map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, onMapReady);
}, false);

function onMapReady() {
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  button.addEventListener("click", onBtnClicked, false);
}

function onBtnClicked() {
  map.showDialog();
}
</script>
```

```
<h3>PhoneGap-GoogleMaps-Plugin</h3>
<div style="width:100%;height:400px" id="map_canvas">

    //SEARCH BOX CODE WHICH DOESN'T WORK
    <div id="searchBox">
        <input type="text" id="query" size="30" />
        <button id="searchBtn">Search</button>
    </div>


</div>
<button id="button">Full Screen</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
  // Define a div tag with id="map_canvas"
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

  // Initialize the map plugin
  var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(mapDiv);

  // You have to wait the MAP_READY event.
  map.on(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, onMapInit);
});

function onMapInit(map){
}
```

PrintScreen of program
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you following part should be change:

```
function onMapReady() {
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  button.addEventListener("click", onBtnClicked, false);
}
```

**to**

```
function onMapReady() {
  var button = document.getElementById("searchBtn");
  button.addEventListener("click", onBtnClicked, false);
}
```